# c++11 struggling to understand why I can't uniform init a structure, but I can init a std::pair of similar type

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization, aggregate-initialization

Given the following code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class test
{
public:
    struct info
    {
        std::string name {""};
        std::function<bool()> func;
    };

    //info my_info { "test_name", [&]{return member_func();} }; // <------ ERROR HERE

    std::pair<std::string, std::function<bool()>> my_info_pair { "test_name", [&]{return member_func();} };

    bool member_func()
    {
        std::cout << "member_func\n";
        return true;
    };

};

int main() {
    std::cout << "start\n";
    test t;
    std::cout << t.my_info_pair.first << std::endl;
    t.my_info_pair.second();
    std::cout << "end\n";
}
```

This code works. But if I uncomment the commented-out line - which is trying to initialise a `info` struct in the same way that the std::pair is initialsing then it fails. I can't figure out why...

The error get is:

```
prog.cc:15:60: error: could not convert '{"test_name", <lambda closure
object>test::<lambda()>{((test*)this)}}' from '<brace-enclosed
initializer list>' to 'test::info'
     info my_info { "test_name", [&]{return member_func();} };
                                                             ^
```

Link to my test code: [here (wandbox)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6bwE4NdntRtXpRQK)

Comment: Why `std::string name {""};`, instead of `std::string name;`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius just to give it a default value i guess.... but actually that probably is not required... :o

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius oh wait... and that makes it work! ...errr, confused!

Comment: @code_fodder 1) "_to give it a default value i guess_" But, `std::string` has default constructor, which constructs an empty string.. 2) "_and that makes it work!_" That's why I asked such a question :)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius ahhh, cool - please add as an answer (maybe with a short explanation why its wrong?) and I'll mark it up : )

Comment: @code_fodder Before asking a question here, please create a [mcve]. You don't need `std::function`, sub class and lot other code to ask this question. e.g. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Sjl7um

Comment: @code_fodder "_please add as an answer (maybe with a short explanation why its wrong?)_" And this is why I didn't write an answer: I found a way to fix it, but I don't have an explanation, of why it wasn't working, with your default initialization.

Comment: @balki ....ehh, you just can't please everyone - I think this is minimal, I made this example from sratch, I put the time in to make it as small as possible. For example: I did not know it was the std::string blah {""} that was causing the problem, for all I knew it had somthing to do with the std::function. With hind site, now that I know the answer - yeah, sure I could make it smaller - but then if I knew that I would not be asking the qusetion ; )

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius haha, fair point - just thought you deserved some credit : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is

```
std::string name {""};
```

You use a in class member initializer, and in C++11, that is not allowed if you want the object to be an aggregate (per [[dcl.init.aggr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.aggr#1)).  To get this to compile in C++11 you have to remove it.

In C++14 and above that constraint was removed (updated [[dcl.init.aggr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.aggr#1)) and in class member initializers are allowed in aggregates and the code will compile as is.

Comment: Maybe use the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) link instead (or in addition).  N3337 is a bit old.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I linked to the old one since the Q is tagged as C++11.  That way they can see the C++11 language.